# C# how to get String Args in a variable

Tags: c#

I got this lines of code (C#)

```
Console.WriteLine("This is you {0}.", someclass.name);
```

What I would like use is this part:

```
private void ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor color, string text)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Problem is, i cannot transfer the string with {0} values into the parameter text from ConsoleWriteColor.

**Solution**:

```
string para = string.Format("Some text {0}",parameter);
```

Comment: You must not edit your question and add solution. Just check one of the answers as right one

Comment: I am not allowd to post any further questions so i looked up in the help center where I was asked to improve questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [params argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) to your ConsoleWriteCOlor like this

```
private void ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor color, string text, params object[] prms)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(text, prms));
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Now you can call it like this

```
ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor.DarkRed, "Hello {0} It is {1}", "Steve", DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString());
```

Beware that this approach has no checking on the correct number of parameters passed to the function. You could pass less arguments than those expected by the format string and get an exception (albeit the same exception happens also writing directly the string.Format without this function)

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Format("Some text {0}",parameter);` this will insert your parameter and return string. And here is example how you can do it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Your code goes here
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor.Red,"Hello {0} and {1}","Arthur","David")
}

private static void ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor color, string text,params object[] a)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(text,a));
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also should check the C# 6.0 [Interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) feature. I think it's more readable *(which you prefer, I hope)*

You don't need to change the method on formatting or plain:

```
private void ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor color, string text)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ResetColor();
}


string name1 = "Arthur";
string name2 = "David";

ConsoleWriteColor(ConsoleColor.Red, $"Hello {name1} and {name2}");  <-- notice the $
```

Comment: Your code won't compile due to the undefined `prms` variable.  You also don't need `string.Format` in the given method.